# Is there a way to get the behavior pack out of a MCworld file?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-behavior-packs

I want to get just the behavior pack out of a world but I don’t know how. Is this even possible?

I want to be able to put the behavior pack onto a realm and the world that it belongs to but when the behavior pack is on it refuses to upload the map to the realm.

I got it from MCPEDL so it is not from the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

## Extracting

Just open the `.mcworld` file with an archiver e.g. WinRAR.  Then go to the `behavior_packs` folder and extract your behavior pack.  If the behavior pack requires a resource pack, then you will need to extract that too.  You can find it in the `resource_packs` folder.

## Installing

To install your behavior pack and/or resource pack, you will need to go to the Minecraft Bedrock directory.  Normally, you can find it here

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_(a bunch of letters)\LocalState\games\com.mojang\
```

Inside that directory, there will be two folders, one called `behavior_packs` and the other called `resource_packs`.  Put your behavior pack(s) and resource pack(s) in their corresponding folders.  Then open/restart Minecraft and now you can use the packs in other worlds.

Comment: Thank you I was able to extract it but how do I exactly put it onto the game? I’m on PC and using windows

Comment: @Khaios check my answer

Comment: @Khaios copy it to your `behavior_packs` folder.  in the Minecraft Bedrock directory.  Normally, the Minecraft Bedrock directory is in `C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang` If the behavior pack requires a resource pack, then you will need to extract that and put it in the `resource_pack` folder in the Minecraft Bedrock directory.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the world you want and then go to `behavior_packs/`. In there will be the behavior pack folders, just copy the folders in there to your `resource_packs` folder in your [Minecraft Appdata](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131551-Where-are-Minecraft-files-stored-).